# Convert OSM data to PostGIS polygons in .net?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, .net

I'm trying to obtain data from OSM and store it to a PostgreSQL + PostGIS database, with certain modifications to adapt to our tables.

Is there any built way to convert OSM [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation)/ways/nodes into [npgsql geometries](http://www.npgsql.org/api/NpgsqlTypes.PostgisGeometry.html)?

I have seen something about [OSMSharp](https://github.com/OsmSharp) to treat OSM data in .Net, but, as far as I have seen, it doesn't help me too much with my case.

I think I won't have too much problem converting it manually(ex: two nodes within a way = line), but would be great to know if there is something that can help me to do it and have been tested already so the majority of edge cases work well.